# Parsing numbers stored as text with comma as decimal and dot as thousands

Tags: python, pandas, number-formatting

I have a Excel file to import with pandas whose columns are stored as text. The caveat is that this text is a number under French/Latin convention for decimals (radix) and thousands, such that by letting pandas infer its type, it brings a text column just as it is presented in the original file:

```
           NUMBER
0   23.639.826,11
1       92.275,00
2    1.917.000,00
8        2.409,02
9       13.501,00
Name: NUMBER, dtype: object
```

How can I make pandas convert this text to the correct float format without having to do the conversion on the Excel file itself or applying string methods to replace the commas and dots?

```
           NUMBER
0     23639826.11
1        92275.00
2      1917000.00
8         2409.02
9        13501.00
```

I have tried using the `thousands='.'` parameter when reading the file with `pd.read_excel` as suggested by the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to no avail and using `pd.to_numeric` outputs a `ValueError` as it is unable to parse the string.

Comment: check with replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `df=pd.read_excel(filename, decimal=',', thousands='.')`

Comment: This solution works for me, but it needs to be `decimal` and `thousands`. Can I ask how you found out about the decimal kwarg?

Comment: I didn't know you could use the `decimal` parameter with this method as well, since the official docs don't list it. Good to know it's easier than I previously thought, thanks!